# Error from nextDouble, how do I fix the problem?

Tags: java

I need to enter 4 decimal numbers to an array and reverse them , I started with the double in the array as you see below but vand.nextDouble function gives me error, I do not want to put the code in misExpection

I tried to change the array but the same problem appears

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UppgiftTolv {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] vand;
        vand = new double[4];

        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Mata in ett tal");
        vand = read.nextDouble();

    }
}
```

Comment: `nextDouble()` most likely returns a double and you try to assign it to an array of doubles... Try to assign it to element of array at some index like `vand[0] = read.nextDouble();`

Answer (score 1):

You need a loop to populate the array as follows:

```
public class UppgiftTolv {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  double[] vand;
  vand = new double[4];
  Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Mata in ett tal: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   vand[i] = read.nextDouble();
  }
 }
}
```

Not that in the code you posted you were assigning a `Double` (result of `nextDouble()`) to an Array of `Double`s.